# PATH set before /etc/zshenv

Tags: path, zsh

I am trying to find which file adds `/opt/texbin` folder to my PATH variable on Ubuntu. It is not present in my `/etc/environment` file. `sudo grep -lr texbin . 2>/dev/null` outputs nothing in the `/etc` folder. And still if I add `set -x` to the beginning of my `/etc/zshenv`  file I can see that `/opt/texbin` is in my PATH before zsh sources this file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it in `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Nope. I checked the file now and it's not in it, neither in any files in profile.d. Also as I said, grepping /etc folder gives nothing :/

Comment: It is possible that it is due to a file in `/etc`, but not directly entered in the file, for instance if it gets `/opt/texbin` from the output of some other command and puts it in `PATH`.

Comment: Makes sense. Couldn't think of a way of testing though -- can you?

Comment: I think I might be able to find it if I was sitting down at your computer, but I'm not sure.....How about giving me SSH access (with `sudo` access, of course)? :)

Comment: What OS are you using? What created the `/opt/texbin` folder?

Comment: Is it in any of the `/etc/z*` files?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Of course, and would you need my bank accounts also? :) My OS is Ubuntu, and /opt/texbin is actually not existing and this is why I am trying to remove it from PATH. I have no idea how it entered into my PATH but I believe it has something to do with Texlive 2013. It is not in any of /etc/z* files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try this approach to track down the source of `/opt/texbin` in your PATH variable:

1. To get a list of files, which are *actually* read in (e.g. a non-standard file might be sourced by another file!), you can invoke `zsh` with the `SOURCE_TRACE` option enabled:

   ```
   $ zsh -o sourcetrace
   +/etc/zshenv:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zcompdump:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zshrc-last:1> <sourcetrace>
   ```
2. Check these files, where the PATH variable come into play:

   ```
   $ grep -ie "path.*=" files_from_step_1
   ```

   The case insensitivity is crucial, since `zsh` uses the array `$path`, which automatically gets converted to the bash-like colon-separated list `$PATH` and vice versa.
3. If still not lucky, try to include a debug message in `/etc/zshenv`, where commands are first read from:

   ```
   print -l $path
   ```

   This will give you a nice list of the PATH variable, which zsh inherits from its parent process (display manager, init process, etc.).<sup>*</sup>
4. If the path is indeed inherited from the starting process, it is crucial to know which processes are relevant:

   ```
   $ pstree -apH $$
   ```

   This produces a process tree, where the shell process (pid in `$$`) is highlighted. Check the config files for these processes, too, and keep in mind that

   - `source /some/file` or `. /some file` can also alter the PATH
   - if you edit e.g. `/etc/profile` in your current console, log off and log in again, the parent process (X logon manager) might still have the old environment.<sup>+</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup> As you have written, the PATH already contains `/opt/texbin` before `/etc/zshenv` is read, checked by `set -x` in `/etc/zshenv`. I get no output with this technique, but with my step 3, hence I included the other steps in my answer as well.

<sup>+</sup>Suffered myself badly due to this behavior some time ago...

Answer (score 3):

The PATH variable that is passed to your shell at log-in is defined in `/etc/login.defs`.  There are two setups here, **ENV_SUPATH** and **ENV_PATH**.  Depending if you login as root or as a user, one of the two is passed to the shell via the environment variable PATH.  After the PATH variable is passed to the shell, any additional changes are controlled by the shell's start-up scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to activate execution trace or source trace at the time `/etc/zshenv` is loaded is to activate it at the shell command: `zsh -l -o xtrace`, `zsh -l -o sourcetrace` -- be sure to try with the `-l` option, since the path element might only be added at login.

Beside this, if you are still getting a path element added before `/etc/zshenv` is loaded, you could check for a `~/.pam_environment` file.  This is the user-local version of the `/etc/environment` file and is loaded at about the same time, before the shell or user environment. Check the man page "pam_env" for more details about the format used - it is different for the user file.

One other minor possibility is the `ENV` environment variable.  When a SH-compatible shell is started in SH-compatible mode, the file whose path is in `ENV` is loaded as a startup file before anything else.  Search your shell's documentation for more detail.  `login.defs` is also used at login and by various user/login utilities, but `/etc/environment` is the standard for all modern login systems and is prefered for establishing the `PATH` variable.