# How to delete old $PATH echo in Mac

Tags: macos, bash, path, zsh

After i changed my Mac username(using the way supplied by Apple Documents), I found that when `echo $PATH`, there are some old paths in it.

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.42/bin:/Users/WaterWood/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/:/Users/majie/.rvm/bin
```

WaterWood is my old username and not exists anymore(I also deleted the folder "/User/WaterWood")

I checked all configuration file, such as .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc, /etc/paths, /etc/paths.d/, but found nothing with "/User/WaterWood".

How to delete these from my $PATH? Thanks.

================

Update:

First I thought it was some bug of oh-my-zsh, and I reinstalled it. It works well, but when i re-login the problem appears again.

Change system shell to zsh(in system preference), run /usr/libexec/path_helper(the result is wrong)

> PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.42/bin:/Users/WaterWood/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/:/Users/majie/.rvm/bin"; export PATH;

Change system shell to bash, run path_helper(the result is correct)

> PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"; export PATH;

I delete all specific configuration in home folder(.zshrc, etc), but also has a "waterwood" in my terminal window, that drives me crazy.

[image]

Comment: May be this can help you, execute commands on '/' path.
grep -R 'Users/WaterWood/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools' *

Comment: @ErdinçTaşkın Thanks for help, but i don't think grep all file in / is a good choice. I tried this before. It costs so much time(and just echo some useless information), so finally i canceled the operation.

Comment: This only execute to finding location of file, i mean, only 1 time is executed. To prevent execute useless information, grep -R 'Users/WaterWood/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools' * 2> /dev/null

Comment: Use `bash -l -v |& WaterWood` when is `WaterWood` being added

Comment: Please have a look at my answer http://superuser.com/a/772516/195224 where I outlined for zsh how to track down the source of a specific path element.

Comment: @janos Yes, i checked /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, and all i know which may influence $PATH.

Comment: @mpy I use your method and checked all the file listed by `zsh -o sourcetrace`. Many of them are in .oh-my-zsh/. Only one weird file is `/Users/majie/.zcompdump-waterwood-5.0.5:1>`(majie is my new username), I delete this file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava When i changed login shell from zsh to bash(in setting preference), everything is OK. That's weird. Maybe i should reinstall oh-my-zsh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization) if you're facing the same problem.

Default configuration file depends on which shell you're using. Back to my question, I forgot to check ~/.zprofile("waterwood" is set in this file).

Answer (score -1):

type

> sudo pico /etc/paths

in terminal , you can the old path just edit and press

> ctrl+O

and hit enter and at last

> ctrl+x

now echo $PATH and see